# React Native adjusting font size of listItem dynamically

Tags: react-native, dynamic, font-size, listitem

[image: Example of text not fitting]
Hi as shown in the picture you canno't see the full text however I don't want to decrease the fonsize for all other items.

Only if it they're greater that 16 in length.

Can I return the fontSize in my renderTitleStyle method or can I do in within the ListItem props e.g `{infoText.length > 16 ? (fontSize: 12) : (fontSize: 32)}` However I don't think this works.

```
  renderTitleStyle = item => {
const infoText = item.location_from + item.location_to;
if (infoText.length > 12) {
  // Return fontSize ???
}
console.warn(infoText.length);
};


        <ListItem
      style={styles.activeUser}
      onPress={() => this.toggleModalConfirmTrip(item)}
      roundAvatar
      subtitle={item.user[0].name}
      titleStyle={this.renderTitleStyle(item)}
      title={`${item.location_from} to ${item.location_to} `}
      ....[![Example of text not fitting][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set styles dynamically by passing an array of styles with a style array element that depends on a state or  a conditional.

```
<Text style={[styles.mainStyles, {fontSize: ((infoText && infoText.length) > 16 ? 12 :32) }]}>
   {/*other elements*/}
</Text>
```

In your specific case i would try passing that condictional as property for `ListItem` Component.

```
titleStyle={this._renderItemTitleStyle(item)}
```

dont forget to create the function.

```
_renderItemTitleStyle = (item) => {
  if (item && Object.keys(item).length) {
    const infoText = item.location_from + item.location_to;
    return {fontSize: (infoText.length > 16 ? 12 :32)}
  }
  console.warn("param item has no properties");
}
```

Comment: Also why use the dangling _ in naming conventions for rendering ? ESLint isn't a fan of it.

Comment: @OscarFen it is just a convention.